# How to push changes till particular commit from one branch to another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have the below commits in branch A 
Commit 9,
commit 8,
commit 7,
commit 6,
.
. 
commit 1

I need to pull the changes till 6th commit and move to some other branch, naming B.

Git reset/hard fails as expected. The old commits, say commit 2 changes are not there after pulling till 6th commit.

Could anyone help me out on this please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also 

benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do, since commit 6 contains commits 1-5 in it's own history. (History is a property of the commit itself.) Therefore, you simply need to create a new branch pointing to commit 6:

```
$ git branch branch_B commit6
```

It's the second form of the command mentioned in the [Git Branch Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

After you've done that, normal Git branch operations will work (like `git checkout branch_B`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While creating branch from the particular commit 6, I'm missing some commits on a particular date. Say I have 19 commits in that day . I missing some commits in the new branch. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you edit your question above to include the output of this command? `git log --pretty=format:"%h %d" --graph master commit6` Your history might reveal what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to checkout to commit 6 using:

```
git checkout #commit6Hash
```

then create new branch using:

```
git checkout -b BranchB
```

now You have changes 1-9 on branch a and changes 1-6 on branch b